# CSS Dropcap Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css

I want to style a Dropcap like that:

[image: 2]

the big letter is aroud 400% of the headlinesize and the text starts under the headline and with the underline of the big letter
if the headline is 2 lines height it's alright but if its only o line it's centered in the middle of the big letter

```
<div class="col-auto d-none d-md-block">
        <span class="dropcap d-block mt-n7">[first letter of the headline]</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col pl-3">
        <p class="h3 dropcap-text">
            headline text
        </p>
        <p>
           Text
        </p>
    </div>
```

I structered like that because on mobile devices the dropcap is a normal letter. And the text should have a left space like the width of the dropcap.

```
.dropcap{
    @media all and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
        text-decoration-color: $primary;
        font-weight: $font-weight-normal;
        font-size: $h3-font-size * 4;
    }
}

.dropcap-text {

    &::first-letter {
        @media all and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
            font-size: 0;       
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried the solution with the float left but I can't get the headline on the bottom of the dropcap with that.

Comment: _“i structered like that because on mobile devices the dropcap is a normal letter.”_ - why would that justify such a weird structure? Nah, this makes little sense. (Same as does putting content that has a supposed “headline” _meaning_, into _paragraph_ elements to begin with.)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with a "Float left" solution?
I have created this Codepen: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/gOwMdOz how is this not what you want? 

Comment: @CBroe naaa its because the margin of the text has to be the same like the width of the dropcap width

Comment: What margin? There isn’t even any in what you have shown us so far. And yes, I agree with @BjørnNyborg, floating is what you _should_ be using here.

Comment: @BjørnNyborg the problem is that the first line of the text starts at the start of the dropcap letter but it shoult start at the end oft the dropcap letter

Comment: What @CBroe said.  Updated the Codepen: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/gOwMdOz

Comment: @CBroe i updated the img so now you see the margin

Comment: @BjørnNyborg yeah ok but now its a headline and it can be 1 to 3 lines and that should aways end with the dropcap letter

Comment: For that kind of dynamic, neither float nor inline will work, something like that you will have to do via flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with an grid, try this:

HTML

```
<div class="dropcap">
        <span class="dropcap-firstletter d-none d-md-inline">
            first letter of the headline
        </span>
        <p class="h3 dropcap-headline">
            headline
        </p>
        <div class="dropcap-text">
            <p>
        text
        </p>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.dropcap {

    @media all and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        column-gap: 10px;
    }

    .dropcap-firstletter {

        @media all and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
            text-decoration: underline;
            line-height: 1;
            text-underline-offset: 0.5rem;
            text-decoration-color: $primary;
            font-weight: $font-weight-normal;
            font-size: $h3-font-size * 4;
        }
    }

    .dropcap-headline {
        align-self: end;

        &::first-letter {
            @media all and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
                font-size: 0;       
            }
        }
    }

    .dropcap-text {
        grid-column-start: 2;
    }

}
```